# Does [DataType(DataType.Currency)] round numbers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

```
[Display(Name = "Price")]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Does `[DataType(DataType.Currency)]` introduce any kind of rounding?

Data annotations only change the display of a model in the View via a html helper and should **not** truncate or round `Price` when saving to the DB - is this correct?

I am running into larger issues with rounding in my models, I am trying to do some root cause elimination..

Comment: No, but by default `EditorFor()` will round a `decimal` to 2 decimal places in the view, so if you then post that back it will be saved as displayed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.